# sliverlight site getting wrong database details

Tags: php, silverlight

I have recently been asked to copy a Silverlight website on a development space. I was sent a zip of all the files plus a db dump.  I set up a new db, set the mime types and uploaded all the files. I put all the site db details into mysite/_config.php

When I turned on error reporting I see that the db connection script looks like its getting its connection details from the old site. Somehow it looks like the site is being directed back to the _config.php file on the live server rather than on my testing one.

Is there a setting somewhere that tells the installation what the domain is that it is sitting on. I have looked and I can't find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `Silverlight` applications use a file named `web.config` (which is part of the project) to look up stuff like database connection strings. Look for the file, open it and do a text search for the old string.

Comment: Thanks Martin - its called _config.php and we have added all the db details in there. There is nothing that I can see however for the url of the site. I have searched the whole site for the url - nothing. Also looked through the db - in wordpress there would be a site settings field...

Comment: Anything URL related could be hardcoded in the silverlight code maybe?

Comment: well, yes that's what I thought. I have searched through the whole code a tonne of times. it must be in there - where else could it be, but I can't fine it!